# Why is an entity file not visible in Spring Tool Suite 4?

Tags: java, git, github, version-control, spring-tool-suite

I'm working on Java Spring Boot, and one day I realized that one of the entities was missing.

[image: Entity missing]

As you can see, there is a file named `Report.java` in the `com.example.demo.entity` package, but there was originally `User.java` file as well.

Because I thought that the User.java was gone at first, I tried to create the file once again by right clicking the entity package and choosing “create a new class”.

But when I try to name the file as User, I’m not allowed to create the file with the same name. I get an error message `“Type with same name but different case exists.”`

I thought it was strange, so I tried `ls command` in GitBash, and then it seemed that the `User.java` still does exist.

[image: git ls command]

But then again it comes back to the first question. Why can’t I see the `User.java` file in Spring Tool Suite, as shown in the first attached image?

I wonder if this has something to do with the other branch. The project I’m currently working on is a school project, and I have 2 git accounts. One is a Git account provided by the school and the other one is my personal GitHub account.

At first I thought of working on the project only with my school git account, but for some reason git pull was not properly working, and the teacher was not sure why and couldn’t fix it either. The teacher told me that he could see all the folders and files that I committed and pushed, so at least I know that commit and push are working on my school git account. Because the final commit on the school git is considered to be a “submission” of the assignment, I must use the school git account.

As I wanted a backup for my half-complete project (and even for the complete one once it’s finished), I decided to use both of my school git account and my personal GitHub account at the same time. So it went through the following process every time I committed and pushed.

```
-> commit and push to my school git (main-branch)

-> switch the branch from my school git (main-branch) to my personal git (master)

-> switch the remote’s URL from my school git to my personal git

-> commit and push to my personal GitHub account (master)

-> switch back to my school git’s branch and remote’s URL
```

I remember that the last time I tried to switch back from my school git to my personal Git, the GitBash didn’t let me switch, giving me an error message like `“You can’t switch back to the master unless you remove or relocate User.java file, otherwise the files will be overwritten”` or something like that.

Because the `User.java` file’s content was rather simple and I made a backup in my Google document, I just deleted the User.java file as a quick solution so that I could switch back to the master branch.

Maybe the problem was that I deleted the User.java file in the main-branch branch (school) before switching back to master branch (personal)? But if so, what should I have done instead? And what now? How should I fix it so that User.java file will be visible again on my master branch in Spring Tool Suite?

By the way, the OS that I'm using is Windows 10.

I made the final commit on the school git and the project itself is complete, so the assignment itself is fine, but I want to save the project on my personal GitHub account as well, because after I graduate from the school I will lose my school git account and no longer have an access to the latest version of the project…. I want to make a backup of my project available online as well. I also want to understand how Git works better.

Comment: I guess you switched between branches using git from the command line, right? Maybe there was an issue with recognizing the file structure change on disc from within the IDE. Did you try to press Refresh (F5) after you switched branches?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I switched via git command line. No, I haven't tried refreshing, but I happened to be able to switch when I tried forcing checkout by the command ```git checkout -f master```, which merges the branches by force, and now the conflicts between my two branches are gone. I appreciate your comment anyway :)